# Is it required to free a pointer variable before using realloc?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

Is it necessary to free memory before using `realloc` again for a pointer variable. Which of the following is correct?

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
   myArray = (int *)realloc(myArray, i*sizeof(int));
}

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
   myArray = (int *)realloc(myArray, i*sizeof(int));
   free(myArray);
   myArray = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The specific usefulness of `realloc` is that you **don't** need to `free` before using it: it exists to grow memory that has already been allocated.

So it is not required and would be uncommon. When passed a `NULL` pointer, `realloc` behaves as `malloc`. If you're using `free` before calling it, you might as well be using `malloc`.

Neither example is correct since you've omitted error handling. All the allocators can return `NULL` and the usage of `realloc` is a little tricky in this respect. Read the docs and examples carefully. Specifically, `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...` is always a bad idea because if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, then you've just lost your reference and leaked memory. Instead use a tmp variable, e.g.:

```
tmp = realloc(ptr, newSize);
if (tmp != NULL)
    ptr = tmp;
else handle_error();
```

Comment: Thanks, which option would be more efficient if one doesn't need to retain the data pointed to by `myArray`?

Comment: If the intermediate `free` is unnecessary then naturally it's more efficient to omit it.

Answer (score 6):

Neither one. You should always check for realloc returning NULL; if you don't, you'll be leaking memory if it does. Also, you're casting the return value of an allocator function, which is [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, you'd better use `sizeof(*myArray)` instead of the explicit `sizeof(type)` construct, because if you later change the type of your array/pointer, and you forget to change the type here also, you'll be facing hard-to-track-down segfault and/or memory leak errors. To sum up:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int *tmp;
    tmp = realloc(myArray, i*sizeof(*myArray));
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        free(myArray);
        /* And handle error */
    }
    myArray = tmp;
}
```

And oh well, to actually answer your question: you don't need to free().

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you want to do.  `realloc()` specifically is designed to take an existing allocation and change its size, preserving as much data as possible.  Both examples you have provided are correct in the sense that they will compile, but they will do different things.

`realloc(NULL, n)` is the same as `malloc(n)`, so the second case is semantically equivalent to:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
   myArray = (int *)malloc(i*sizeof(int));
   free(myArray);
   myArray = NULL;
}
```

In the first example, the data pointed to by `myArray` will be retained.  In the second example, the existing allocation will be thrown away and replaced with a brand new, uninitialized allocation.  Any data pointed to by the original allocation will be discarded.

---

It should be noted that `realloc()` will return `NULL` if the allocation fails -- but if you passed it a non-`NULL` pointer then that allocation will not have been freed.  Passing one pointer into `realloc()` and assigning the result *directly* into that same pointer variable can cause a memory leak if the reallocation fails, because the original allocation will still exist.  The correct way to do this is to use a temporary pointer variable.

Answer (score 2):

No. Why? The whole point of `realloc` is that it reallocates the existing memory block, preserving the values already stored in that memory block. The idea is that in some cases it might reuse the existing memory location instead of allocating a completely new memory block and copying the old values there.

If you don't care to preserve the content of the old block, then you might not need `realloc` at all.

It should also be mentioned that `realloc`'s capabilities also cover `malloc`'s and `free`'s functionality, given the appropriate argument values. What you are doing in the second cycle of your code is essentially using `realloc` in pure `malloc` mode.